# Last cell of UITableView disappears automatically after some time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view in one view controller with five cells on clicking of which I redirect to some other view controller. The issue is that whenever I come back the view controller that contains the table view, the contents of the last cell in the table view automatically disappears.

Here is the code for my tableview:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    logoimg=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"account_settings.png", @"account_settings_onclick.png",@"invite_friends.png", @"invite_friends_onclick.png", @"leaderboard.png", @"leaderboard_onclick.png", @"setting.png",@"setting_onclick.png", @"logout.png", @"logout_onclick.png", nil];
    logoname=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Account Settings", @"Invite Friends",@"Leaderboard",@"Settings",@"Logout",nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 45;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section       {
    return logoname.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    UIImage *logoOff = [UIImage imageNamed:[logoimg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]];
    UIImage *logoOn = [UIImage imageNamed:[logoimg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2+1]];
    UIButton *logo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [logo setBackgroundImage:logoOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logo setBackgroundImage:logoOn forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [logo setBackgroundImage:logoOn forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    logo.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, logoOff.size.width/2, logoOff.size.height/2);
    logo.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    logo.tag = indexPath.row;
    logo.selected = FALSE;
    //[bottomView addSubview:logo];


    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,13, cell.contentView.frame.size.width-70, 20)];
    [name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic" size:14]];
    name.numberOfLines = 2;
    name.text=[logoname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [name sizeToFit];
    name.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImageView *divider = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    divider.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"divider_line.png"];
    divider.frame = CGRectMake(0, 43, self.view.frame.size.width ,2);

    [cell.contentView addSubview:logo];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:name];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:divider];

    return cell;
}
```

The **logoname** and **logoimage** are two `NSMutableArrays`.

If any more code is needed let me know I will provide the necessary code.

Comment: please check that are you getting all data in array by `NSLog();` in console when u come back to the view by applying necessary breakpoints.

Comment: I have tried by adding breakpoints and I am getting all the data in the array but still the contents of the last cell is not visible

Comment: Can you please check in -viewWillAppear that you are getting all data in logoname , if you are getting all the data then please check in numberOfRowsInSection and make sure for last cell you are able to fetch the data. Also just try to scroll and then check if you are able to see the data. To explain you better , it would be great if you can post more code

Comment: show some code here add all tableview's delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: Code of which method....

Comment: Replace the logoName.count with 5 and check if problem still exist.

Comment: I have tried that also but nothing happneded

Comment: wy dont u try with subclassing the  UITableViewCell cell

Comment: But I want to know what is the issue in this case

Comment: But u are not reusing the contents of cell dont u see, each time u are adding the subview's to cell

Comment: @improgrammer i just posted the sample code by subclassing the cell, hope this might helps u .. :)

Comment: Ok I will try this...and let u know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52294/discussion-between-shan-and-improgrammer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better u need to subclass the tableview because, each time you are reusing the cell, but its subview are not, so just do like this

create a new file and name it as `MyCustomCell` subclass of `UITableViewCell`
in `MyCustomCell.h` file

```
 MyCustomCell.h
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *logoOff;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *logoOn;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *logo;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *name;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *divider;

 @end
```

in MyCustomCell.m file

```
 MyCustomCell.m
 #import "MyCustomCell.h"

 @implementation MyCustomCell
 @synthesize logoOn;
 @synthesize logoOff;
 @synthesize logo;
 @synthesize name;
 @synthesize divider;


 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.logo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.logo.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.logo.selected = FALSE;

    self.name = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic" size:14]];
    self.name.numberOfLines = 2;

    self.name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.name sizeToFit];
    self.name.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.divider = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

    [self.contentView addSubview:logo];
    [self.contentView addSubview:name];
    [self.contentView addSubview:divider];

  }
   return self;
}

 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 - (void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];
   //  set the frames for all subviews
   [self.logo setBackgroundImage:self.logoOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [self.logo setBackgroundImage:self.logoOn forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   [self.logo setBackgroundImage:self.logoOn forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    self.logo.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, self.logoOff.size.width/2, self.logoOff.size.height/2);
    self.name.frame = CGRectMake(70,13, self.bounds.size.width-70, 20);
    self.divider.frame = CGRectMake(0, 43, self.bounds.size.width ,2);

}


@end
```

and in the controller

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
     if(cell == nil)
     {
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
     }
     cell.logoOff = [UIImage imageNamed:[logoimg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]];
     cell.logoOn  = [UIImage imageNamed:[logoimg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]];
     cell.name.text =  [logoname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // cell.divider.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"divider_line.png"]; //for test i commented 
    cell.divider.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
 }
```

Hope this helps u :)

Comment: @improgrammer comment if u hav any problem